# How can I access components of the Modelica library in an easily viewable format?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I'm working on viewing FLUIDS right now. I want something with this format to be viewable/printed. I'm using the Python OpenModelica to access the Modelica Standard Library.

[Image of a Fluid component that I'd like to have access to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7rb2.png)

It'd also be great if this is accessed in a way that allows the data to be parsed through and analyzed as well.

I'm using OpenModelica, and I can run simulations but not access individual components.

Comment: Please post your code as text in the future instead of using an image.

Answer (score 1):

Slight variation of the other answer.
In particular the Sink is seen as a FixedBoundary, not a tank.

Note that you need to select the Medium - using exactly the same syntax in all components, *including* the sink.

```
model Unnamed
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.MassFlowSource_T boundary(
    redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
    m_flow=0.1,
    T(displayUnit="degC") = 293.15,        nPorts=1)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-118,0},{-98,20}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe(
    redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
    length=5,
    diameter=0.05)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-60,0},{-40,20}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary boundary1(redeclare package Medium = 
        Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,nPorts=1)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{46,4},{26,24}})));
equation 
  connect(boundary.ports[1], pipe.port_a)
    annotation (Line(points={{-98,10},{-60,10}},  color={0,127,255}));
  connect(boundary1.ports[1], pipe.port_b) annotation (Line(points={{26,14},{-34,
          14},{-34,10},{-40,10}}, color={0,127,255}));
  annotation (uses(Modelica(version="4.0.0")));
end Unnamed;
```

You use slightly different names in your example. I cannot find them in the Modelica Standard Library. It simulates with some minor issues in Dymola.

Comment: Simulates in OpenModelica. But better from start to include the missing declaration of the independent Fluid.System (that the compiler do for you). That is  code: inner Modelica.Fluid.System system(energyDynamics=Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.FixedInitial); - which I also missed in my first attempt above.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sufficiently used to MSL Fluid and Media but here is a partial answer and hope that someone else can improve it.

First I recommend you to use OMEdit and startup with MSL 4.0.

You can create a similar example to what I think you want by

```
1. Making a new model
2. Drag in the following components:
   1. Modelica.Fluid.Sources.MassFlowSource_T - call it source
   2. Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe - call it pipe
   3. Modelica.Fluid.Vessel.OpenTank - call it tank
3. Connect them
```

Then you get the following block diagram

[image]

and below the corresponding code.

[image]

The next step is to choose the right media and then set the other parameters. I think you want to use: "Modelica.Water.WaterIF97_ph"

The following error list I got before giving any media

[image]

When I try to give each component this media I get some errors and not sure what to do.

Try to get some inspiration from examples in Modelica.Fluid.Tanks ...